# Overhead associated with systemd using Arch linux on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi, systemd

Having problems with a custom process that I start at boot time using systemd.  I am using the Arch Linux distro built for the RPi.  There is nothing special about the service I'm starting.  Its a server listening on a UDP port for a proprietary protocol responding to requests appropriately (written in C).  The problem I am having is when the service is started via systemd, the client has timeout issues every few seconds as queries and responses are sent to and from the server.  When I run the service from the command line after I log in, I experience none of these timeout issues.  I suspect that there is some kind of process monitoring overhead associated with systemd that is causing a slight slowdown.  Is there any documentation describing the types of monitoring overhead that systemd imposes, and how to shut it off?  My .service file for the service is trivially simple, following the examples.

As a second approach, I am considering trying the Wheezy distro to see if I get similar timeout issues since I believe the init system is something other than systemd.  I want to try this, but I'm not ready to abandon Arch and the effort I've put in.

Comment: Welcome to superuser! Maybe your question will get more attention on http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com though

Comment: As far as I know the only things that systemd uses to monitor services are logging of the output and cgroups. Cgroups are built into the kernel directly and I don't think they create much overhead.